# reading mysql to webpage with express and javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to print a list from mysql table to express page.

app.js uses routes.js. there I have get for users profile page

```
//profile
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  var courses = [];
  connection.query('SELECT courseID FROM studentCourses WHERE userID = ?', [req.user], function(err, rows){
    for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
      courses.push(rows[i]);
    }
    for(var j=0; j< courses.length; j++){
      connection.query('SELECT name FROM courses WHERE courseID = ?', [courses[j]], function(err, rows2){
        list = rows2[j];
      });
    }
  });

  res.render('profile', {
    user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
  },
  {
    courses : list
  }
  );
});
```

my mysql tables

users:
id, username, password

courses:
id, name

studentCourses:
id, userid, courseid

I am trying to list all course names that a user with id 2 have for example.

Cant find a descent tutorial for nodejs  and mysql.
This is as far as i could go but couldnt make it work.

Probably its just a wrong way.

Any help listing that table to a ejs web template would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: Regarding your MySQL query, you can join the tables and make one single connection request to your db.  

`SELECT * FROM studentCourses sc LEFT JOIN courses c ON sc.courseid = c.id WHERE sc.userID = ?`

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project requirements like this before, where MySQL is retrieved using NodeJS.

I can verify that this module will work with your requirements. The name of the module is [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/) where you can map your MySQL tables into a Javascript Objects.

> Bookshelf is a JavaScript ORM for Node.js, built on the Knex SQL query builder. Featuring both promise based and traditional callback interfaces, providing transaction support, eager/nested-eager relation loading, polymorphic associations, and support for one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-many relations.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the structures I like to follow for a simple CRUD application.

db.js exports a simple wrapper function `query` which will be used to make all queries to MySQL

#### db.js

```
var logger = require("./logger"),
    config = require("config"),
    mysql = require("mysql");

var pool  = mysql.createPool(config.get("mysql"));

module.exports.query = function(){

    var sql,params,callback;
    if(arguments.length===2) {

        sql = arguments[0];
        params = [];
        callback = arguments[1];
    }
    else if(arguments.length===3) {

        sql = arguments[0];
        params = arguments[1];
        callback = arguments[2];
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Invalid number of arguments");
    }

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        connection.query(sql,params, function(err,rows) {
            if(err) {
                logger.error(err);
            }
            callback(err,rows);
            connection.release();
        });
    });
};
```

#### app.js

```
var express = require("express"),
    db = require("./db");

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/profile", isLoggedIn, function (req,res) {

    var sql = "SELECT a.name FROM courses a INNER JOIN studentCourses b ON a.courseID=b.courseID WHERE b.userID=? ";
    var params = [req.user];

    db.query(sql,params,function (err,result) {
        if(err) {
            res.render("wrong");
        }
        else {
            res.render("profile",{
                user : req.user,
                courses : result,
            });
        }
    });
});
```

#### profile.ejs

```
<h2>User Id - <%= user %></h2>
<ul>
    <% courses.forEach(function(course) { %>
        <li><%= course %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```